# How do I close an SSH connection with a background process without killing it?

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to know how I can close an ssh connection to a linux server where I started a process brought to background (by adding `&` at the end of it) without killing the process.
If I simply do `exit`, this seems to kill the process.

Comment: Use `GNU Screen` https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ instead of backgrounding a process.

Comment: Start the process with `nohup` and the `&`.  For example, `nohup some-long-running-process &`.  Although as @Nikita Kipriyanov suggested, `screen` is a much better option.

Comment: thanks! if you're happy with it please write it as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: If your use case is just a one-off job, go with the already proposed solutions. However, if by any chance your use case is to ssh to the server to start an application or service that will run continuously, you may want to look at a systemd service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the comments: Start the process with `nohup` and the `&`. For example, `nohup some-long-running-process &`. Although as @Nikita Kipriyanov suggested, `GNU screen` https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ is a much better option.